# Issue with Wacom tablet and Asus laptop

Tags: asus-laptop, graphics-tablet

I upgraded to an Asus laptop.

[image]

I am using a Wacom pen tablet model CTL 490 CTH.
All drivers are up to date.
I am using this configuration with Adobe Elements 2019.
The issue is that while using the pen to edit a photo, for instance trying to paint, often/usually when touching the tablet, the screen will display a small white circle as if it is "thinking" and then it will display a pop up menu to change brush size. I have already selected brush size and do not want to change. Does anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Comment: The tablet (or Adobe) is maybe set to too-short a time for when a continuous touch is taken to be a right-click. Check parameters.

Comment: Thank you harrymc. I don't seem to be able to find any settings like that. Still looking and tinkering ;)